# How to hide tabs in windows terminal through its settings file?

Tags: windows-10, json, windows-terminal

I’ve spent almost an hour on trying to figure this out but I have not quite figured it out.

Also, where can I find an exhaustive list of what's settings can be changed in the `.json` file? Microsoft docs page seems to be very brief on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to hide tabs in windows terminal through its settings file?

I don't have Windows 10 to test this for you but it seems you need to use a combination of settings:

- `alwaysShowTabs` set to false
- `showTabsInTitlebar` set to false

> When this [`alwaysShowTabs`] is set to false and `showTabsInTitlebar`
> is set to false, tabs only appear after more than one tab exists by
> typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> or by typing the
> key binding assigned to `newTab`.
>
> Note that changing this setting will require starting a new terminal
> instance.

Source [Windows Terminal Global Settings | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/global-settings)

---

#### Where can I find an exhaustive list of what's settings can be changed

The links below list all of the `json` setings currently documented by Microsoft.

> The properties listed below affect the entire terminal window, regardless of the profile settings. These should be placed at the root of your settings.json file:

Source [Windows Terminal Global Settings | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/global-settings)

> The settings listed below are specific to each unique profile. If you'd like a setting to apply to all of your profiles, you can add it to the defaults section above the list of profiles in your settings.json file:

Source: [Windows Terminal Profile Settings | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings)

> Color schemes can be defined in the schemes array of your settings.json file:

Source [Windows Terminal Color Schemes | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes)

> Key bindings can be structured in the following formats:

Source [Windows Terminal Key Bindings | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings)

Comment: Hey this did it, it was very helpfull thank you for taking the time to write it.

` "alwaysShowTabs": false,   
    "showTabsInTitlebar": false,`